I'm getting a 404 error when trying to load an image through flask html by using the url_for static expression
I am trying to load an image through static but getting 404 error.
Here's my code
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=images/cat.png)}}" alt="new image">
    <img src="{{url_for('static' filename=photo.png)}}" alt="new photo">

all my filepaths seem to be correct but the image is still not loading. When i just use the normal way of putting an image in HTML, the image shows up. for ex -
<img src="/static/images/cat.png" alt="photo Image">

here's the filepaths of the project in pycharm


I recommend to use Direct Path rather than url_for in this case, and it would look something like this:
<!-- Using direct path -->
<img src="/static/images/cat.png" alt="photo Image">
<img src="/static/photo.png" alt="new photo">

However if you insist on using url_for, You need to use the correct syntax:
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/cat.png') }}" alt="new image">
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='photo.png') }}" alt="new photo">


Thanks for the response!
The direct path is working however the url_for is still not working - even with your code.

Oh that's interesting that it's not working, But it is a lot more common using the Direct Path in these scenarios.

yeah, can't figure out what the issue is. Can you please double check the filepaths image I've shared and confirm there are no issues with the way I've managed them?

The file path looks good to me, it might be some tiny error in the rest of the code or just a python version thing. I don't have a clear idea on it. Happy that it works tho!

You have an issue with your syntax, specifically with the quotes. Try this code instead:
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/casual.JPG') }}" alt="new image">
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='photo.png') }}" alt="new photo">


Thanks for the response! I used your code but the image is still not loading! Is there anything else that I could try?

Share the contents of the /images directory so we can have better clue of the file tree.
